# Definition/body of the printf & scanf function in C

Tags: c, header-files, turbo-c

Where do i find the definition/body of the printf/scanf & other similar predefined commonly used functions (getch, clrsr ...etc) of "Borland C" ?

Comment: Of the Borland implementation? Nowhere, it's closed source. But you can download e. g. the source of the GNU libc, that's probably even better (standards-conformant, significantly higher quality, etc.)

Comment: what's the name of the header that you must include to use this functions ?

Comment: They should be in the 'standard C library' that comes with the compiler, or the 'standard C library' that's already installed on the system.  The header for `printf()` and `scanf()` etc is `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : that's where the *declaration* would be, for sure - the OP is specifically asking for *definition*. Unless they include sources for the std library, it's likely not included with product.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Unless `printf()` is inlined, I don't think that's going to be true...

Comment: The compiled definition of the `printf()` function (for example) is going to be in the relevant library.  The source body of the function is probably not available — period.  If you need to get a program to compile, you need the compiled definition of `printf()` from the library.  You don't need the source for `printf()` unless you're planning to modify its code — and people who are planning to do that don't need to ask this question.  I double-checked that it was not the same person asking this question as [Borland 5.5 C Compiler not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028520/15168).

Comment: Wasn't about Borland, but same concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350231/where-can-i-find-source-code-to-to-truly-understand-what-the-standard-function.  As H2CO3 said though, you're not likely to come across the Borland source.

Comment: Where's the `Standard C Library` located for borland or GNU gcc?

`I wanted to know the core working of the standard function's (by observing their definition) like :

    How system fetches date from inner core system using time() ?
    What's happen's when printf is called ? `

Are the definition of above function's written in Assembly????

Comment: @H2CO3: if "Borland C" refers to the command-line compiler, then you are right that the RTL source is not provided. But if it refers to the "Borland C++Builder" product instead, then it does include RTL source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot.. You can just see the prototype of **printf/scanf** in the header file `<stdio.h>`

You can find it in the standard library which comes with whatever compiler you are using..

Comment: Where's the `Standard C Library` located for borland or GNU gcc?

`I wanted to know the core working of the standard function's (by observing their definition) like :

    How system fetches date from inner core system using time() ?
    What's happen's when printf is called ?`

Are the definition of above function's written in Assembly????

Comment: Source code for glibc can be found here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/
However, be aware that it's NOT "easy to read" source.

Comment: And most of glibc is not writen in assembler, but a few small pieces are for performance reasons. Or because the code is not possible to achieve in C.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you cannot see the source code of predefined functions like printf() and scanf() since they are already compiled file with extension of .lib the compiler just need the declaration of function and doesn't need exact source file they are link later by linker to produce .exe file.